# Stop countdown angularjs

Tags: angularjs, countdown

I've this code and I want to stop the countdown when when it reaches 00:00. I want to use `$interval.cancel();` but I don't know how to use it.

My code is here :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
     $scope.counter = 10;   
     $interval(function(){console.log($scope.counter--)},1000);
});
app.filter('counter', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>{{counter | counter | date:'mm:ss'}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's why documentation exists: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Ive already see but it seems to me complicated the documentation for so little

Comment: If it's complicated for you to read documentation, then you shouldn't be a programmer. It's part of the job. Do you realize that your question is basically "I'm too lazy to read a page of documentation. So could you please write the code for me?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add condition like `counter != 0` and clear the interval.

According to [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) you need the promise to cancel interval.

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
         $scope.counter = 10;
         var intervalTime=null;   
         intervalTime= $interval(function(){console.log($scope.counter--); 
         if($scope.counter == 0){
              $interval.cancel(intervalTime);
              intervalTime = null;
         }
},1000);
    });
    app.filter('counter', [function() {
        return function(seconds) {
            return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
        };
    }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>{{counter | counter | date:'mm:ss'}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much